# Count the posts number for every category

Tags: categories, sort

I'd like to count the number of posts created for every category, so:

```
12 Works (12 posts in works category)
36 Pictures (36 posts in pictures category)
17 Furnitures (17 posts in furnitures category)
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use wp_list_categories() function and set show_count to 1 (true)
 http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories